# UWP - Pivot IsTabStop not working as expected

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a pivot that I am trying to keep from gaining focus when the user hits the tab key. I immediately tried to set IsTabStop to false. However this wasn't keeping a user from tabbing into the pivot. So I tried testing IsTabStop on two buttons and the behavior was exactly what I expected from the pivot.

Here is my xaml:

```
<Pivot IsTabStop="False">
    <PivotItem Header="Test">
        <StackPanel Spacing="10">
            <Button Content="Button 1" IsTabStop="True"/>
            <Button Content="Button 2" IsTabStop="False"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

Am I missing something here or is there a way around this?

Comment: What if you set it for all controls inside pivot table to false.. Otherwise try setting tabbing index/order or override the tabbing completely with your own manual focus setting..

Comment: I've tried setting the tab stop to false on all the controls inside as well as the pivot item, nothing changes. I've also tried setting the tab index on the pivot to -1, still no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what i ended up doing is overriding the default style on the pivot. I changed the "HeaderClipper" in the style to have IsTabStop="False", this fixed my problem.

The documentation for the default pivot style can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299144.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Setting tab index to -1 only makes it first, try something like 1001.. In here they explain the issue you may be having but for RichTextBlock, there are various attributes available for it to set.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/accessibility/keyboard-accessibility

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, based off the documentation i believe that will just put it last in the tab index order.

Comment: If you want to use a hack you can set its index to 1 when last control is in focus, and set it to 1001 when first one is..